Woocommerce Schedule Sale Start Date Issue
I am trying programmatically  set  a sale start date.
I am using:

function mysalesdates( $product, $sale_start,$sale_end ) { 
  if ( ! is_a( $product, 'WC_Product' ) ) {
    $product = wc_get_product( $product );
  }

  if ( ! $product ) {
    return false;
  }
    $product->set_date_on_sale_from( $sale_start);
    $product->set_date_on_sale_to( $sale_end );
    $product->save();
 
    return;
  }

  $sale_start=strtotime("01 Jul 2024"); 
  $sale_end =strtotime("31 July 2024");
// I already have the product id stored in $myproduct_id from another function
  $product_saledates = mysalesdates($myproduct_id,$sale_start,$sale_end);


And I can verify  that it adds the date to the _postmeta  database  and the sale start date shows as 2024-07-01 in Sale price dates when I edit the product.
The problem is that the although the product shows as 'on sale', there is the ON SALE badge  over the product image.  The product is showing the regular price and not the sale price.  eg it shows Original price was: £15.71.Current price is: £15.71. inc VAT and does not show the sale price in the database.
If I edit the product and change nothing but simply save it  then it works.
is there something that I need to call programmatically that does something that saving a product does  to make this work.
Ican programmatically change prices, changes stock levels etc but for some reason woo does not act on the sale start date unless I then manually save the product,
Thanks
Steve

There are some mistakes in your code and there is no function or method that set or update the "sale price date from".
From an existing WC_Product object, you need to use  set_date_on_sale_from() method like:
$date_from = strtotime('01 Jul 2024');

$product->set_date_on_sale_from( $date_from );
$product->save();

Now it should work.

This is the right answer. Always go for WooCommerce API (WC_Product::set_date_on_sale_from) instead of manually setting meta data.

Thanks  But It's still not showing the sales price when I load the product page.
I'll paste the function I created and try and explain the problem better by edititng the question.

@Steve It depends on where and how you are using this code… This is the right way. You should edit your question, giving more context on where and how you are using the code...

The Revised code I posted is working , Thanks  to LoicTheAztec's for pointing me  in the right direction.
The strange this is  that is Woocommerce did not show the sale prices instantly  so there must be some caching going on.
I still had the issue of all the right prices and dates in database  but woocommerce was not showing the sales prices, but it has sorted itself overnight without me doing anything further.
